# How to migrate AWS resources across regions?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have been using AWS for nearly 2 years with most of my resources (EC2, ELB, RDS, Elasticache) deployed into Ireland (eu-west-1), mostly due to latency. In January, AWS opened a new region -- Cape Town (af-south-1) -- which has less latency.
I wonder how can I easily move all of my resources across to the new Region?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot move your resources from one region to another, you will be limited to recreating resources and migrating any data into the region that you're looking to use.

Best practice for managing and maintaining your infrastructure is to use infrastructure as code, if you already have this in place it should be as simple as running this into the new region you intend to use. Otherwise this will need to be done from scratch, whilst you don't need infrastructure as code I would definitely recommend this approach in the event that you need to do any similar tasks in the future (such as another migration or a disaster recovery scenario).

Be aware that certain services are also global (such as IAM and CloudFront) so these will not need any such migration.

For migrating of data there are a few services that assist in delivering this:

- [AWS Data Pipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/)
- [AWS Database Migration Service](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an AMI of the existing instances and then you can share them across different regions or accounts. See link:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/sharingamis-explicit.html